# Strapi Components not showing

Tags: strapi, nuxt-strapi

So, I have a Strapi app that I migrated from v3 to v4 (v4.9.0) and now, after migration the components are not showing in my app. For example I will provide the code for the footer component.

This is my column.json from my src/component/footer

```
{
  "collectionName": "components_footer_columns",
  "info": {
    "icon": "columns",
    "description": "",
    "displayName": "Columns"
  },
  "options": {},
  "attributes": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "links": {
      "type": "component",
      "repeatable": true,
      "component": "header.sublinks"
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my schema.js from src/api/footer-menu/content-types

```
{
  "kind": "singleType",
  "collectionName": "footer_menus",
  "info": {
    "singularName": "footer-menu",
    "pluralName": "footer-menus",
    "displayName": "Footer-menu",
    "name": "footer-menu"
  },
  "options": {
    "increments": true,
    "timestamps": true,
    "draftAndPublish": true
  },
  "pluginOptions": {},
  "attributes": {
    "columns": {
      "type": "component",
      "repeatable": true,
      "component": "footer.column"
    },
    "customcolumn": {
      "type": "component",
      "repeatable": false,
      "component": "footer.custom-column"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that in v3 all worked perfectly, now once with migration all my components are not showing, not just my footer. The api s are working fine. Also, the footer components is populated with data from database. I checked and the db have no problem.

My footer-menu now:[image]

And this is how the footer should look like:[image]

Comment: Try with ?polulate=‘*’  if you want to populate deeper there is plugin that does that for you